# Cannot adjust y position of custom view in titleView for nav bar

Tags: ios, navigationbar

Hey I am trying to add a custom view to a navigation bar. The current result is like so:

[image]

I initialise this navigation bar like so:

```
 func setupNavBar() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        let navBarView = ExamCoachNavBarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 236, height: 45))
        navigationItem.titleView = navBarView
    }
```

I want to move the custom view down to the bottom of the nav bar. I have tried changing the `y` value for the `navBarView` frame. This make absolutely no difference those. Regardless to what that value is the frame always stays in the same position at the top of the bar. What am I doing wrong here? How can I move the bar to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Why do you set `y: 300`? Try with `y: 0` and for easy debug, add background color for the `ExamCoachNavBarView`

Comment: @Scott.N tried that. The position always remains the same.

Comment: You should add a testing background color for `navBarView` and see how to this view display on the screen and compare the height you set and height it renders.

Comment: I tried changing the background color of the `navBarView` but oddly it doesn't show any colour. Just those labels like the image above. @Scott.N

Comment: @Scott.N seems to be related to using a view initialized from a xib file. If I create a view programatically I can adjust the view's frame and background color. If I try to initialize from a .xib it won't work.